# type of item for in app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

how to get info about an product for in app purchase like wether item is consumable or non consumable etc ? SKProduct give me only productidentifier ,price , title and localized title etc ?

Comment: The solutions suggested below seem like a hack to me. It is annoying that Apple doesn't simply provide the type. This would be useful to be able to write generic code that displays the product differently depending on the type of product being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you (as the developer) define which products/items can be "restored" then you should already know if it's a consumable (non-restorable) or non-consumable (restorable) item.

If needed you can make a call to [restoreCompletedTransactions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) to get back information on all non-consumable items the user has purchased (for example if they're running the app on a new phone).

Comment: means as a developer i m going to define about that item is consumable or not ? is it ok. To retrive back info about product calling restoreCompletedTransactions is enough ? app store take care of this and giving appropriate msg to user? or i need to do in my code? 
thanks

Comment: A call to restoreCompletedTransactions will only return information about items that are non-consumable. There's sample code and lots of documentation on the Apple Developer site, including instructions on how to test your in-app purchase system, which might give you a better idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This code will get you going: works on the simulator too: https://github.com/boxerab/InAppPurchase